# How can I limit the selectable cells in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

In my application I have a `UICollectionView` with 12 x 4 squares. I want that the user can only selected 4 in a row of them in the same cycle. How can I block the other rows? I read something about headers in `UITableView`, but this did not work in the `UICollectionView`

Comment: You can check your condition before the cell is selected with the collectionview's delegate https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618095-collectionview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
var firstIndex = -1
var lastIndex = -1
var arraySelectedIndexes = [Int]()
var setEligibleIndexesForSelection = Set<Int>()

let numerOfItems = 20
```

I have tried to consider all scenarios :

```
extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        switch (self.setEligibleIndexesForSelection.contains(indexPath.row), self.arraySelectedIndexes.count == 0) {
        case (false,false):
            return false
        default:
            return true
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.arraySelectedIndexes.append(indexPath.row)
        self.arraySelectedIndexes.sort()

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        self.firstIndex = self.arraySelectedIndexes[0]
        self.lastIndex = self.arraySelectedIndexes[self.arraySelectedIndexes.count - 1]

        self.updateEligibleIndexArray()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let indexOfSelectedData = self.arraySelectedIndexes.firstIndex(of: indexPath.row)
    self.arraySelectedIndexes.remove(at: indexOfSelectedData!)

        if self.arraySelectedIndexes.count > 0 {
            self.firstIndex = self.arraySelectedIndexes[0]
            self.lastIndex = self.arraySelectedIndexes[self.arraySelectedIndexes.count - 1]
            self.updateEligibleIndexArray()
        }
        else {
            self.firstIndex = -1
            self.lastIndex = -1
            self.setEligibleIndexesForSelection.removeAll()
        }

        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    }

    func updateEligibleIndexArray() {
        self.setEligibleIndexesForSelection.removeAll()

        for i in self.firstIndex..<self.firstIndex+4 {
            if i < self.numerOfItems && !self.arraySelectedIndexes.contains(i) {
                self.setEligibleIndexesForSelection.insert(i)
            }
        }

        for i in self.lastIndex-3..<self.lastIndex {
            if i >= 0 && !self.arraySelectedIndexes.contains(i) {
                self.setEligibleIndexesForSelection.insert(i)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I may have missed few scenarios so do let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: Yeah this worked perfectly for me thank you very much :D

Comment: How can I do this, that the first row which is selectable is the one on the top?

Answer (score 2):

Implement below mentioned `UICollectionViewDelegate`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.count <=  4
}
```

Comment: Doesnt this just limit the amount? I want for example that just [0,1] - [0,4] is selectable / [0,5] - [0,8] and so on

Comment: you can update `collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.count <=  4` with your own logic.

Answer (score 1):

Define following variables:

```
var firstSelectedIndex: Int?
var nextEligibleCount: Int = 0
```

Then update the collectionView delegate method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0, 4, 8, 12:
        firstSelectedIndex = indexPath.row
        print("-----New row click has been started------")
        print(String(indexPath.row) + " is clicked")
        nextEligibleCount = 1
    default:
        checkClick(atIndex: indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

***checkClick()*** is defined as below:

```
func checkClick(atIndex selectedIndex: Int) {
    if firstSelectedIndex != nil {
        if selectedIndex == firstSelectedIndex! + nextEligibleCount {
            print(String(selectedIndex) + " is clicked")
            nextEligibleCount = nextEligibleCount + 1
        } else {
            print("Invalid click")
        }
    }
}
```